# enterText() in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

i am new in android testing, I try to calculate two values using Edit Text. i tried in two ways. One way is solo.enterText(EditText edittext, String text); and another one is solo,enterText(int index, String text);

This one is working for me

```
//Access First value (editfiled) and putting firstNumber value in it
EditText FirsteditText = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText01);
solo.enterText(FirsteditText, String.valueOf("10"));
```

This one is not working for me

```
solo.enterText(0, "10");
```

whats the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [Solo.enterText](https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java#L1224)

> index: the index of the EditText. 0 if only one is available

You'll need to use 1 for the fist EditText if there is more than one available in your current layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try without creating first the EditText object :

```
solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(ID),value);
```

EG :

```
solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(R.id.number_one_value),"13");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two way to input Edit Text:

1. By EditText id.

   ```
   EditText FirsteditText = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText01);
   ```
2. By Index. This index is the index of editText that displays in current activity. If there is only one editText, use 0. If there are more than 1 editText, use 1, 2...

Answer (score 0):

use this statement:

```
String.valueOf(): in -- solo.enterText(0,String.valueOf("10"));
```

It worked for me.